# Exclude child elements from functions with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

With the code below:

```
<p>Red red red red <a href="http://www.google.com"> this should be red alone</a> red red</p>
```

How would I change all 'red's to 'yellow's EXCEPT the one in the 'a' tag?

I've got this far:

```
$("p").html(function(i,event){
    return event.replace(/(red)/g,'yellow');
});
```

...which changes everything to yellow. I assume I need to add in an if clause saying something along the lines of:

```
if (event.target.tagName === "a")
{return false}
```

But I've tried dozens of things I've found on stackoverflow, to no effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate the text nodes using `contents()`. This will not have any impact on any event listeners on the inner elements the way using `html()` would

```js
$('p').contents().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType === 3) {
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(/red/gi, function(match) {
      return match === 'Red' ? 'Yellow' : 'yellow'
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Red red red red <a href="http://www.google.com">red</a> red red</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I asked.... I'm afraid I'm learning that simplifying my problems on stackoverflow for brevity is  not always sensible though! My actual problem involves making the <p>Red</p>s into hyperlinks: hence needing to exclude the text already in hyperlinks. Using textContent doesn't work, as it's no longer adding in html... Sorry!  Any ideas though?

Comment: Thanks Charlie - think I can use that!

Answer (score 1):

Dirty way because too specific and won't work if many `<a>` in `<p>` for instance, but works if in `<p>` there is only one `<a>`.

The best way is to figure out the right regex.

```js
var aContent = $('p > a')[0].outerHTML;

$('p').html(function(i,event) {
    var parts  = event.split(aContent);

    for (var i, l = parts.length; i<l; i++) {
        parts[i] = parts[i].replace(/red/ig, 'yellow');
    }

    return parts.join(aContent);
});
```

```html
<p>Red red red red <a href="http://www.google.com">red</a> red red</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice, but I oversimplified my problem - the link could have other words in. I've updated my question above...

Comment: @JohnG it's more a `regex` problem, updated my answer if it's of any help, otherwise I updated your post to include notify `regex` experienced people

Answer (score 0):

I took another route: isolate the child, replace its place with random text, perform our replace as usual and then replace that random string with our child code back again.

```js
var para = $("p");
var child = para.children()[0];
var text = child.outerHTML;

para.find(child).replaceWith("zzzz");

$(para).html(function(i,event){
    return event.replace(/(red)/gi,'yellow');
});

$(para).html(function(i,event){
   return event.replace("zzzz", text );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>Red red red red <a href="http://www.google.com"> this should be red alone</a> red red</p>
```